# Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error :

Tags: twitter-oauth

I am working to establish the connection with twitter using R. Need help to resolve this error:

> Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
>   This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()

The code is:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)

customer_key <- "XXXX"
customer_secret <- "XXXX"
access_token <- "XXXX"
access_secret <- "XXXX"

download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_secret)

[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

I also referred to similar answers, but couldn't resolve this error. I have tried the following :

- used a library(base64enc)
- Checked the firewall issue, have allowed the R application in Windows defender firewall settings using command prompt -

  ```
  netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="app name" dir=in action=allow program="Full path of .exe" enable=yes
  ```
- Uninstalled R and have installed the latest version.
- Have tried replacing (library(twitteR) and library(ROAuth)) with (library(openssl) and library(httpuv)).
- Have tried using all the 4 libraries (twitteR, ROAuth, openssl, httpuv) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
```

to:

```
library("openssl")
library("httpuv")
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the working directory? Create New Folder on the desktop named hows you want then set the working directory as that... Try to regenerate code ```library("openssl")
library("httpuv")
library("twitteR")
library("tm")
library("stringr")
library("dplyr")

api_key <- " code"
api_secret <- "code"
access_token <- "code"
access_secret <- "code"

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_secret)
origop <- options("httr_oauth_cache")
options(httr_oauth_cache = TRUE)```

Comment: Thanks ! 
I am able to proceed further :)